# Filtering the email tracking dashboard based on value in DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, dataextensions, dashboard, email-studio

I am sending out one email template in different languages to my subscribers (the language is based on a "Language" Field in a DE, and with some simple AmpScript logic I display the correct language in the email).

However, since it is a single email, the tracking dashboard (opens, clicks etc.) being created is an aggregation of all the different languages of that one email.

Is there a way I can filter the dashboard based on the Language value in my DE? So let's say, I want to see only the email data in the dashboard where Language = EN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way (depending on how many languages) would be to send a "different" email to each language and associate each email to a single campaign. Then in the tracking dashboard you could split results based on email name or look at the overall results with the campaign name filter.

Alternatively you could create a custom send log and insert the jobId and language associate with the subscriber into a data extension to join to the system data views later. (sends, opens, clicks etc)